# Canonical URLs in sortable paginated lists

Tags: seo, canonical-url, pagination

How should one use `rel="canonical"` in sortable paginated lists?

An unsorted list of products is not the same as the same list sorted, nor are lists sorted in different ways equivalent. For example, compare:

- `http://www.example.com/desktops?sort=p.price&order=ASC&limit=5&page=2` with
- `http://www.example.com/desktops?sort=p.price&order=DESC&limit=5&page=2`

These are two very different pages, but they have the same canonical URL. Surely this is incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using `rel`-`canonical` for these URLs would be (most of the time) incorrect. [*RFC 6596* defines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596#section-3):

> The target (canonical) IRI MUST identify content that is either duplicative or a superset of the content at the context (referring) IRI.

This is not the case for your content.

If you have a page that lists *all* products (without pagination), you could use its URL as the `canonical` URL for the paginated URLs. If you don’t have such a page, don’t use `rel`-`canonical`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am going to use canonical on the first page only, because without it I have many similar pages in webmaster tools. Example: http://bit.ly/KrJd55 http://d.pr/i/wuXQ+

Comment: @user66638: You shouldn’t use the first page as canonical URL either.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should not use `rel="canonical"` on pages with duplicate content that seek to merely "play" the search engines.

I believe that `rel="canonical"` is to be used in situations where duplicate content is necessary to better explain a certain product on a site.